# KCallable doesn't work in Kotlin when one of the parameters is vararg

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have an issue where I have a class that stores a `KCallable<Any>` and calls it using parameters passed in by an interpreter that's running a custom scripting language. This works for most functions when I use `KCallable.call()`, but it doesn't seem to properly handle functions with a `vararg` parameter, instead assuming that the parameter is an array of the given type. Is there any way I can work around this issue using some sort of reflection method to convert the input for the parameters? Here's my current code:

```
class KotlinFunction(function: KCallable<Any>) {
    fun call(args: List<Any>) {
        function.call(*args.toTypedArray())
    }
}
```

given the function as class member:

```
fun concat(vararg xs: String) = xs.reduce{l,r -> l + r}
```

Using 3 parameters, I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Callable expects 1 arguments, but 3 were provided.

Answer (score 1):

The way that the `vararg` argument works is by collecting the multiple values into an `Array`, and passing that into the function. Therefore, your function `concat` is actually a function that takes an `Array<String>` as its single argument, and a reference to it is of type `KFunction1<Array<out String>, String>`.

So to call it with your setup, what you need to do is pass in the `Array` representing the `vararg` arguments inside a `List`, making this `Array` the only argument going into the `KCallable#call` method after spreading the list:

```
val kf = KotlinFunction(::concat)
kf.call(listOf(arrayOf("a", "b", "c")))

class KotlinFunction(val function: KCallable<Any>) {
    fun call(args: List<Any>) {
        // Here, `call` will be invoked with one parameter, the Array,
        // as that's the only element in the List
        function.call(*args.toTypedArray())
    }
}
```